# REQUEST_URI return single slash

Tags: php

I Use this part of code to print `canonical` tag:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])){
$url = strtok($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'?'); 
?>
<link rel="canonical" href="https://mywebsite.com<?=urldecode($url);?>" />
<?php
} else {
?>
<link rel="canonical" href="https://mywebsite.com" />
<?php
}
?>
```

But it not going to ready `else` condition if current `URL` is `https://mywebsite.com`. I found out why, because `var_dump($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);` return `string(1) "/"`. Why when I open this URL `REQUEST_URI` return `/` while there is no slash at tail?

Anyway, beside of this question, how can I solve my code to working?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/fa/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 4):

In a HTTP call `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` can never be `empty` unless it is `unset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` or `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI] = ''` by the script itself.

For a HTTP call to `http://mywebsite.com`, it will hold `/` as its value. That's what you are getting. `/` denotes root of the website, so when HTTP request is made to the root of the website, `/` is sent as path and will always be present, whether you add it or not into the URL.

I think that clarifies why you are not hitting `else` condition of your code ever.

Coming to your problem, if you want to append the path to the url without any query parameters, the better approach for this should be:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://mywebsite.com<?php echo parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH); ?>">
```

This replaces all of your code. You may want to take a look at [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function of PHP.

If you don't want the trailing slash intentionally, you can make use of [`rtrim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php).

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://mywebsite.com<?php echo rtrim(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH), '/'); ?>">
```

In case, you are passing any valid URL to `parse_url` and don't want trailing slash only for root, then:

```
<?php
$path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
if($path == '/' || !$path) {
  $path = '';
} ?>
<link rel="canonical" href="https://mywebsite.com<?php echo $path; ?>">
```

Comment: Yes thanks for explanation but your code not working, nothing changed, still return `<link rel="canonical" href="https://mywebsite.com/">`

Comment: That's expected output. A link pointing to [`https://stackoverflow.com/`](https://stackoverflow.com/) and [`https://stackoverflow.com`](https://stackoverflow.com) are functionally same.

Comment: Check for updated answer, if you specifically want to remove trailing slash.